# Rails bundler: how to undo bundle package?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, package, bundle

How do I undo `bundle package`?

I deleted everything in `vendor/cache` but it is reinstalled there when I run `bundle install`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to I undo the vendor/gems bundle install](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9471970/how-to-i-undo-the-vendor-gems-bundle-install)

Answer (score 13):

As per this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9471980/219883

You must delete the hidden `.bundle` directory, then re-run `bundle install` - otherwise it will continue to add the `vendor/cache` directory back every time.

Answer (score 8):

But if you just to remove a particular gem, then remove/comment the name of the gem from your project/Gemfile and then run bundle.

To prevent gem files from being added to the vendor/cache directory delete the vendor/cache directory from your project root.

The next time you will run bundle install gems won't create a vendor/cache folder.

Later on in your project if you need the vendor/cache folder all you'll have to do is to create the folder vendor/cache again.

Comment: I want to undo what bundle package did!

Comment: So you want your vendor/cache folder to remain empty .. is it ?

Comment: "The next time you will run bundle install gems won't create a vendor/cache folder."
This is not true... I delete the vendor/cache directory and re-run bundle install and it just adds the vendor/cache directory back again - every time.

Answer (score 4):

`.bundle/config` is telling bundler to put things in `vendor/cache`. Either remove the following two lines from `.bundle/config` or remove `.bundle/config` itself.

```
---
BUNDLE_PATH: vendor/cache
BUNDLE_DISABLE_SHARED_GEMS: '1'
```

Then run the following command to remove `vendor/cache`:

```
rm -rf vendor/cache
```

The next time you run `bundle install` you will not have this problem.

Answer (score 3):

```
$ rm vendor/cache -r
$ bundle install
```

Comment: This does not work for me. It adds back the vendor/cache directory - every time.

Comment: The problem is that .bundle/config is telling bundler to put things elsewhere.  Delete the offending line/s.

Answer (score 3):

This might help as well. For more details see the documentation on [bundle install](http://gembundler.com/bundle_install.html)

```
bundle install --system
```

Answer (score 3):

Pretty late to answer, but this was happening with me too. You probably have hidden directory `.bundle` in you application root directory. Remove that directory too and then run `bundle` command.

Answer (score 1):

You can check your config with (under your project directory):

```
bundle config
```

it outputs something like:

> Set for the current user (/Users/user/.bundle/config):
>   "--with-cppflags=-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include"

In the config file you can check your config setting.

If there's no anything strange like:

```
BUNDLE_PATH: vendor/cache
```

You can easily remove `vendor/cache` directory and run `bundle install` again

In other way just remove the config variable from the file and repeat ^^

P.S. If you met gems storing under your project. It's probably previous developers worked with private repos and to avoid problems with deploy and private repositories, they solved to store the gems under project directory. So just make sure you will not break your deploy after removing the gems dir.

Answer (score 0):

Bundler 1.2 has support for :git and :path but it has to be explicitly enabled like this

```
bundle package --all
```