# How to I undo the vendor/gems bundle install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rvm, bundle, bundler

I ran `bundle install vendor/gems` and all the gems got saved to the gems directory as expected but when i delete them like

```
rm -rf vendor/gems

rails s
 Could not find rake-0.9.2.2 in any of the sources
 Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

I need to run bundle install again and all the gems install to the `vendor/gems` again. Is there a way to get this behavior to stop and just install as I used to using my .rvmrc file and not package the gems in the vendor/gems directory

Answer (score 55, accepted):

There is a hidden directory called `.bundle` in the root of your directory.  Remove that, then run bundle again.

Comment: I have a Rails 5.2 app and I couldn't find `.bundle` directory in root(infect anywhere withing app) of the app. Any idea how stop caching gems in `vendor/cache` with newer versions of Rails?

Comment: I'm using Rails 6 now and i can still see the `.bundle` directory in root. Are you using an OS that hides "hidden files" from you?

Comment: Removing the folder when not having a `.bundle` was enough for me