# How do i do a case insensitive search based on this url

Tags: ruby, regex, case-insensitive

Here is the url i am trying to match

```
/anyfirsturl/apPles/1
```

the first part can be anything

```
/^\/[\w]*\/apples\i
```

This regular expression doesnt match anything so far

I want it so the user can enter in APPLES or APPles or any way or for and any number after

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
/^\/[\w]*\/(apples)\/\d+$/i
```

the i option will do a case insensitive search, and should match all of those permutations.

Comment: figured it out...i had to put the i after

Comment: Ok so then accept/ up vote my answer to this and the bundler question I answered for you please!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9471970/how-to-i-undo-the-vendor-gems-bundle-install/9471980#9471980  thanks.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
url =~ %r{^/.*/apples/\d+$}i
```

Comment: where is the documentation for =~